# Using Dompdf to view .pdf from CakePHP 2 page

Tags: cakephp, pdf, dompdf

I have just downloaded `dompdf-0.6.1` and want to use it in my CakePHP 2.0.5 application.

I have included `Router::parseExtensions('json', 'pdf');` in routes.php and created a default.ctp in app -> View -> Layouts.

```
<?php

require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php');
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

I want to allow a user to view an income statement as a .pdf file - which can be printed. The income statement takes the parameters of startDate and endDate for generation.

The file below is the income_statement.ctp. What do I need to do in order to allow a user to view the statement as .pdf by pressing on a link on the browser page?

```
.......some code...... 

 <div style="text-align:  center">

        <h1><?php echo $this->Session->read("Business.name"); ?><br>Income Statement</h1>
        <h3>
            For period starting <?php echo $startDate; ?> to <?php echo $endDate; ?>
        </h3>
        <table align="center" width="400px;">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left;" colspan="2">Revenue</td>
            </tr>
           ........code.........
                <td style="text-align: left;">
                    <?php
                    $space = "&nbsp;";
                    for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++)
                        echo $space;
                    ?>
                    <b>Total Operating Expenses</b>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><b><?php echo number_format($totalExpenses + $saleDiscount, 2); ?></b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: right"><?php echo $totalDescription; ?></th>
                <th style="text-align: right"><?php echo number_format($net, 2); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </table>      

    ....Link for view as pdf.....
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either save the pdfs as actual files and then link to them (link to site.com/pdf/filename.pdf):

```
public function action() {
    $view = new View(null, false);
    $view->set(compact('variable1', 'variable2'));
    $view->viewPath = 'Folder';
    $output = $view->render('income_statement', 'layout');

    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
    $dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($output), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
    $dompdf->render();
    file_put_contents(APP . 'webroot' . DS . 'pdf' . DS .'filename.pdf');
}
```

Or, you can just echo what $dompdf returns from the render, and just change your page's headers (link to site.com/controller/action.pdf):

```
public function action() {
   $this->layout = $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->header(array('Content-type' => 'application/pdf'));

   //Code for generating pdf data similar to above

    echo $dompdf->render();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Questions: I place the function in the controller...will the pdf have the same formatting as the html view (never used dompdf before)? Explain array('Content-type' => 'application/pdf').

Comment: As for "Explain array("Content-type" => "application/pdf");", please read the CakePHP cookbook regarding setting headers.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers  If you are not already aware, an HTTP response includes headers that define a bunch of information that browsers need to display, so if you change the content type to pdf, the browser will attempt to display/download a pdf.

Comment: As for "will the pdf have the same formatting as the html view?"  Yes, as long as you tell it to use the same layout, view file, etc.  When I use DomPDF.  My code is actually just circumventing CakePHP's autorender feature, and then calling render on the view manually, so I can capture its output in a variable.  You don't always have to do DomPDf's that way, but I've found depending on what you're trying to do, sometimes you may have to, or at least it makes it easier.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Kai. Went with 1st option.